# Should cudaMemset work on the device pointer mapped from cudaHostRegister

Tags: cuda, mapped-memory

I came across the sample code from one of my colleagues where the cudaMemset doesn't seem to work properly, when run on V100.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#define CUDACHECK(cmd) \
{\
    cudaError_t error  = cmd;\
    if (error != cudaSuccess) { \
        fprintf(stderr, "info: '%s'(%d) at %s:%d\n", cudaGetErrorString(error), error,__FILE__, __LINE__);\
          }\
}

__global__ void setValue(int value, int* A_d) {
     int tx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
     if(tx == 0){
         A_d[tx] =  A_d[tx] + value;
     }
}

__global__ void printValue(int* A_d) {
     int tx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
     if(tx == 0){
         printf("A_d: %d\n", A_d[tx]);
     }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[ ]){
        int *A_h, *A_d;
        int size = sizeof(int);
        A_h = (int*)malloc(size);
        A_h[0] = 1;
        CUDACHECK(cudaSetDevice(0));
        CUDACHECK(cudaHostRegister(A_h, size, 0));
        CUDACHECK(cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void**)&A_d, A_h, 0));
        setValue<<<64,1,0,0>>>(5, A_d);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        printf("A_h: %d\n", A_h[0]);
        A_h[0] = 100;
        printf("A_h: %d\n",A_h[0]);
        printValue<<<64,1,0,0>>>(A_d);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        CUDACHECK (cudaMemset(A_d, 1, size) );
        printf("A_h: %d\n",A_h[0]);
        printValue<<<64,1,0,0>>>(A_d);
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        cudaHostUnregister(A_h);
        free(A_h);
}
```

When this sample is compiled and run, the output is seen as below.

```
/usr/local/cuda-11.0/bin/nvcc memsettest.cu -o test
./test
A_h: 6
A_h: 100
A_d: 100
A_h: 16843009
A_d: 16843009
```

We expect A_h and A_d to be set to 1 with cudaMemset. But it is set to some huge value as seen.
So, is cudaMemset expected to work on the device pointer A_d returned by cudaHostGetDevicePointer.
Is this A_d expected to be used only in kernels.
We also see that cudaMemcpy DtoH or HtoD seem to be working on the same device pointer A_d.
Can someone help us with the correct behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We expect A_h and A_d to be set to 1 with cudaMemset.

You're confused about how `cudaMemset` works.  Conceptually, it is very similar to `memset` from the C standard library.  You should try your same test case with `memset` and see what it does.

Anyway, `cudaMemset` takes a pointer, a **byte** value, and a size **in bytes** to set, just like `memset`.

So your `cudaMemset` command:

```
    CUDACHECK (cudaMemset(A_d, 1, size) );
```

is setting *each byte* to 1.  Since `size` is 4, that means that you are setting `A_d[0]` to `0x01010101` (in hexadecimal).  If you plug that value into your windows programmer calculator, the value is 16843009 in decimal.  So everything is working as expected, here, from what I can see.

Again, I'm pretty sure you would see the same behavior with `memset` for the same test case/usage.

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the clarification. That means A_d 's value here can be modified either by changing A_h or by using cudaMemcpy if i m right. And cudaMemset can be used if we want to set A_d to 0.

Comment: Yes, `cudaMemset` can be used to set integer and floating point quantities to zero.  It's less useful for trying to set those types to other values.